# Adding jagged arrays beginner

Tags: java, arrays, jagged-arrays

I'm a beginner at java at struggling with this:

I am trying to sum two jagged arrays ( n and m, both double [][]) of the same size (each is length 3 at the first level, then of length x-1,x and x-1 respectively at the second level).

The problem I'm having is to specify the length that each array within the jagged array should be, at the moment my code is producing an n x n array because I've specified the length as n[1] rather than as a parameter, but if I try and use sum[i].length=n[i].length I get the error, "cannot assign value to final variable". So I know this part is wrong but I don't know what is right...

Thanks for the help!

My code:

```
else if (isValidTridiagonal(m)== true && isValidTridiagonal (n) == true)
{
    int size = n[1].length; /** specifying all lengths to be x where they shouldnt be*/
sum = new double[3][size];

for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j< n[i].length; j++)
    {
        sum [i][j]= n[i][j] + m [i][j];
    }
}
return sum;
```

}

Comment: You may want to include your variable declarations.  It looks like you already asked this question (and it was closed as a duplicate) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40530278/beginner-adding-jagged-arrays-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some missing information. As far as I can tell there are two things you need to fix. You seem to have "sum" as a final variable already defined in your code.

Secondly, you are declaring a new array that is 3xsize big. If you want a jagged array in that sence, you must leave one of the brackets empty and in the first loop insert a new array of the wanted size.

```
double[][] sum = new double[3][]; //Make sure this is unique within the scope
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) { //if you want dynamic scaling you'll need to replace 3 in the array as well.
    int size = n[i].length; //size of the new row
    sum[i] = new double[size]; // Inserting a new array of the wanted size
    for(int j = 0; j< sum[i].length; j++) 
    {
        sum[i][j]= n[i][j] + m[i][j]; 
    }
}
return sum;
```

Comment: Glad I could help! :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably with this line:

```
sum = new double[3][size];
```

Here you create an incorrect, non-jagged array of size [3][2]

When you try to set sum[1][2] (2nd, 3rd index), you will not be able to.

Otherwise, the code looks correct and I got a sum to work using this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[][] n = new int[3][];
  n[0] = new int[2];
  n[0][0] = 1;
  n[1] = new int[3];
  n[2] = new int[2];

  int[][] m = new int[3][];
  m[0] = new int[2];
  m[1] = new int[3];
  m[1][2] = 1;
  m[2] = new int[2];

  int[][] sum = new int[3][];
  sum[0] = new int[2];
  sum[1] = new int[3];
  sum[2] = new int[2];

  for (int i = 0; i < n.length; i++) { // n.length will be 3
    for (int j = 0; j < n[i].length; j++) { // n[i].length will be 2, 3 and 2
      sum[i][j] = n[i][j] + m[i][j];
    }
  }

  System.out.println("Sum: ");
  for (int i = 0; i < sum.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < sum[i].length; j++) {
      System.out.print(sum[i][j] + "|");
    }
    System.out.println();
  }
}
```

This will print off:

```
Sum: 
1|0|
0|0|1|
0|0|
```